# SqlAlchemy Changing an additional field on an association object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble figuring out how I would change the primary field value in TblEventsContacts from the event record with the following database setup.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy import orm

import uuid

Base = declarative_base()
Session = orm.sessionmaker()
Engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///arandomdb', echo=True)
Session.configure(bind=Engine)
session = Session()



class TblContactsContacts(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tbl_contacts_contacts'

    parent_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey('tbl_contacts.guid'), primary_key=True)
    child_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey('tbl_contacts.guid'), primary_key=True)


class TblEventsEvents(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tbl_events_events'

    parent_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey('tbl_events.guid'), primary_key=True)
    child_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey('tbl_events.guid'), primary_key=True)

class TblEvents(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_events'
    guid = sa.Column(sa.String(36), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)

    children = orm.relationship('TblEvents',
                                secondary='tbl_events_events',
                                primaryjoin='TblEvents.guid==TblEventsEvents.parent_id',
                                secondaryjoin='TblEvents.guid==TblEventsEvents.child_id',
                                )

    contacts = orm.relationship('TblContacts', secondary='tbl_events_contacts', backref='events')


class TblContacts(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tbl_contacts'

    guid = sa.Column(sa.String(36), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = sa.Column('contact', sa.String)

    children = orm.relationship('TblContacts',
                                secondary='tbl_contacts_contacts',
                                primaryjoin='TblContacts.guid==TblContactsContacts.parent_id',
                                secondaryjoin='TblContacts.guid==TblContactsContacts.child_id',
                                )


class TblEventsContacts(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tbl_events_contacts'

    event_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey(TblEvents.guid), primary_key=True)
    contact_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey(TblContacts.guid), primary_key=True)
    primary = sa.Column(sa.Boolean)

    event = orm.relationship('TblEvents',
                             backref=orm.backref('contacts_assoc',
                                                 passive_deletes='all'
                             ))
    contact = orm.relationship('TblContacts',
                               backref=orm.backref('events_assoc',
                                                   passive_deletes='all'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all(Engine)

    ev1 = TblEvents(guid=str(uuid.uuid4()), name='event 1')
    con1 = TblContacts(guid=str(uuid.uuid4()), name='contact 1')
    session.add(ev1, con1)
    session.commit()

    ev1.contacts.append(con1)
    session.commit()
```

I feel like this is the closest I have gotten.

```
ev1.contacts[0].events_assoc.primary = True
session.commit()
```

Do I have to use a query or is there a way to do this in orm? It doesn't complain when I do this, but it also doesn't do anything. So I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I was closer than I thought. It ended up being this.

```
ev1.contacts[0].events_assoc[0].primary = True
session.commit()
```

Just missing the index specifier after events_assoc